# How to log in LibGdx while running desktop:run?

Tags: java, libgdx, desktop-application

I cannot see logs when I run desktop:run on Android Studio.
My log message is simple:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    viewport = new ExtendViewport(WORLD_WIDTH, WORLD_HEIGHT);
    buttonNewGame = EpheButton.newInstance(
            "New Game",
            WORLD_WIDTH / 2,
            WORLD_HEIGHT - 50,
            viewport.getCamera().combined);
    Gdx.app.log("Tag", "Debug message");

}
```

Should I edit the configuration for the desktop:run task?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check log level setting. Your issue looks like log level `Application.LOG_NONE` is enabled:

```
Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_NONE);
```

**Don't use** `System.out.println("Your log")` - it's not logging system. With it you miss cross platform logging benefits of LibGDX:

> Depending on the platform, the messages are logged to the console (desktop), LogCat (Android) or a GWT TextArea provided in the GwtApplicationConfiguration or created automatically (html5).

Read more about LibGDX [logging system](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Logging)